# How to set the byte that an output stream points to?

Tags: java, file-io

Is it possible to set the byte that a `FileOutputStream` points to? I have a header in my file in which I leave some empty bytes. Once I write the file I have to go back and overwrite those empty bytes. Is there a way to do this without opening the file twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a java.io.RandomAccessFile for this.